# How to convert UTC to IST time format

Tags: javascript, angular, date, datetime, time

Input:- 2018-01-19T17:04:54.923Z;

Output:- 2018-01-19 17:04:54;

How can I get universal logic which will work in all browsers in JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var dt = new Date('2018-01-19T17:04:54.923Z');

var formatedString = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + dt.getMonth() + 1 + "-" + dt.getDate() + " " + dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();


console.log(formatedString);
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful, even when they answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can convert UTC date to local date format using below snippets.

```js
// Your input date
var utcDate = new Date('2018-01-19T17:04:54.923Z');

//Converted UTC to local(IST, etc.,,)
console.log(utcDate.toUTCString());
/* 
  Output is : "Fri, 19 Jan 2018 17:04:54 GMT"
*/
```

Comment: The result of [*toUTCString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) is implementation dependent and may or may not be in the OP's required format (most likely not).